# Does cPanel pass along security updates from installed software (Mediawiki, WordPress, etc) in a timely manner?

Tags: security, cpanel, installation

I have an account with a bare-bones cPanel based web-host and I'd like to run a CMS from this account. (MediaWiki or WordPress. I've not decided yet. I hope that doesn't matter for this question.)

There is a custom "easy to use" installer for both CMS packages within cPanel. Can I reasonably expect security updates to be available promptly? Or, am I better off downloading and installing over FTP if this is my concern?

Note that I'm not asking if the various CMS packages themselves release security updates, but how quickly those updates will find their way into the cPanel ecosystem. If there is no set policy, how fast have those updates taken in the past?

Comment: Sorry but there's no right or wrong answer since updates of the installers changes daily, sometimes WordPress for example via the installer will be latest and sometimes it may be outdated.

Comment: @SimonHayter - I've edited the question to focus on cpanel specifically.

Comment: You're referring to [Softaculous](https://www.softaculous.com/softaculous/) which is NOT made by cPanel. Softaculous is updated daily however most hosts disable this option. As it differs from host to host, you really should be speaking to the host your paying, they will tell you how often its updated. Furthermore including WordPress as an example is pointless because WordPress 3.7 introduced automatic updates.

Comment: @SimonHayter That comment should be an answer.